# Display: Inline-block is positioning the element below

Tags: html, css

I have an extremely basic side by side layout which I'm trying to achieve however it seems to be pushing the element down.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ca616067/1/

```
.whitebox {            
    background-color: #fff;            
    height: 200px;   
    display: inline-block;        
}
```

I have fixed it by using;

```
Display:inline-block;
position:relative;
top:-185px;
```

Is there a better way to fix this problem?

Comment: Side note: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: @j08691 sorry, I copied it and forgot to delete some of the irrelevant bits, I have updated the questions with new JSFiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align` on your block level elements to bring them in alignment with each other.

You can view this [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onqyw49x/1/)

Comment: Be sure to update your fiddle and post the new link :)

Comment: Thanks, a simple copy and paste error!

Comment: @MrDeveloper Thank you, this worked better than floating

Comment: This solution also works and may be preferable to my approach (using `float:left`) depending on context.

Comment: `vertical-align` only applies to inline-level and table-cell elements. Not to block-level elements. Fortunately, the elements are inline-level.

Answer (score 2):

Both the image and `.whitebox` are inline-level boxes in the same [line box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#line-box).

Therefore, their vertical alignment is specified by the [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) property:

> This property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of
>   the boxes generated by an inline-level element.

By default, its value is `baseline`:

> Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If
>   the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with
>   the parent's baseline.

Since the image does not have a baseline, its bottom margin edge will be aligned with the baseline of `.whitebox`. That baseline is calculated according to

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

Therefore, you can

- Change the vertical alignment of the image and `.whitebox`, e.g.

  ```css
  img, .whitebox {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  body {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
  }
  h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #535353;
  }
  .forR {
    width: 980px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .inline {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
  }
  .whitebox {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .box1 {
    width: 737px;
  }
  img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  img, .whitebox {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <div class="forR">
    <img src="http://cumbrianrun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/default-placeholder.png">
    <div class="whitebox box1">
      <p class="inline">Name: Matthew</p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Make sure `.whitebox` has no in-flow line box, so that the baseline of `.whitebox` will be its bottom margin edge. That is, the contents should be [out of flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x23):

  > An element is called *out of flow* if it is floated, absolutely
  >   positioned, or is the root element. An element is called *in-flow* if it
  >   is not out-of-flow.

  So for example you can use `float: left`:

  ```css
  .whitebox > * {
    float: left;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  body {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
  }
  h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #535353;
  }
  .forR {
    width: 980px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .inline {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
  }
  .whitebox {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .box1 {
    width: 737px;
  }
  img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .whitebox > * {
    float: left;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <div class="forR">
    <img src="http://cumbrianrun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/default-placeholder.png">
    <div class="whitebox box1">
      <p class="inline">Name: Matthew</p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Set the `overflow` of `.whitebox` to something different than `visible`, so that the baseline of `.whitebox` will be its bottom margin edge.

  For example, `overflow: hidden`:

  ```css
  .whitebox {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  body {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
  }
  h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #535353;
  }
  .forR {
    width: 980px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .inline {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
  }
  .whitebox {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .box1 {
    width: 737px;
  }
  img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .whitebox {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <div class="forR">
    <img src="http://cumbrianrun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/default-placeholder.png">
    <div class="whitebox box1">
      <p class="inline">Name: Matthew</p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
      <p class="inline"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Sure! In this case, you can use CSS `float: left;` as below and in [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqsinger/ca616067/3/):

```
.inline {
    display: inline;    
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: haha, that seemed simple :) thank you, I will mark it as answered in 7mins when I can. TY

Comment: No problem :) depending on how you use the class `.inline`, you might want to separate out `float: left;` into another class.

Comment: `display: inline` is useless when using float, it will be blockified to `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what it is but it seems to fix itself once you remove all the paragraphs with class of inline.

```
<div class="whitebox box1"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwORMe

Comment: I believe its because the <p> have inline assigned to them which I need, but the vertical alignment worked great, thank you anyway.